# Transferring order values from php shopping cart to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart, checkout

I am trying to setup a “checkout/order” page within a site in which logged in users earn points/credits. Once they earn a certain amount of these points they can then go to a shopping cart and pay with these points only. (No money changes hands, so no paypal/checkout/shipping/taxes etc are involved).

I have done a 'shopping cart' page and 'view cart' page (view cart code is on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012081/disabling-checkout-button-from-shopping-cart-php)), which works fine thanks to Steve and KMK ;).

I have two tables on my MySQL database, 'orders' (which has order id, users id, total & time stamp) and 'order_contents' (order contents id, order id, product id, quantity and price). 'total' is total price, 'price' is price per product.

I am trying to get the items that the user selects (ie products, quantity etc) from the view cart page into the 'order' and 'order_contents' tables in the database via the **submit_cart.php** file (code below) but it isn't working properly.

**What does work on this code** is that it puts a new row/order_id into the orders table, as well as the users_id.

**What doesn't work:** The total price of the order doesn't get inserted (shows up as '0' on the database) and it displays the first error message (with the 1 on the end).

Nothing gets inserted into the 'order_contents' table either, at this point I am assuming it is because the insert into the 'orders' table isn't working or somehow the cart session variables are not going across(?) but I am happy to be corrected...

If someone could lend a hand or even suggest a different approach please feel free! Thanks!

```
<?php 
$page_title = 'Order Confirmation';
include ('./includes/header.html');

if (!isset($_SESSION['users_id'])) {

   // Start defining the URL.
   $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
    . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   // Check for a trailing slash.
   if ((substr($url, -1) == '/') OR (substr($url, -1) == '\\') ) {
        $url = substr ($url, 0, -1); // Chop off the slash.
   }
   // Add the page.
   $url .= '/login.php'; 

ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
header("Location: $url"); 
exit(); // Quit the script.
}

$users = $_SESSION['users_id']; // Temporary.

$total = 0; // Total cost of the order.

require_once ('/MySQL/database.php'); // Connect to the database.

@mysqli_autocommit ($dbc, FALSE);

$query = "INSERT INTO orders (users_id, total) VALUES
   ($users, $total)";
$result = @mysql_query($query);
if (@mysql_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {

// Need the order ID.
$oid = @mysql_insert_id($dbc);

// Insert the specific order contents into the database.
$query = "INSERT INTO order_contents (order_id, products_id, quantity, price)
   VALUES (";foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $pid =>$value) {
$query .= "$oid, $pid, {$value['quantity']}, {$value['price']})";
}
$query = substr($query, 0, -2); // Chop off last two characters.
$result = @mysql_query($query);

// Report on the success.
if (@mysql_affected_rows($dbc) == count($_SESSION['cart'])) { // Whohoo!

// Commit the transaction.
@mysqli_commit($dbc);
@mysql_close($dbc);

// Clear the cart.
unset($_SESSION['cart']);

// Message to the customer.
echo '<p>Thank you for your order.
   It has been submitted for processing.</p>';

// Send emails and do whatever else.

} else { // Rollback and report the problem.

@mysqli_rollback($dbc);
@mysql_close($dbc);

echo '<p>Your order could not be processed due to a system error.
   You will be contacted in order to have the problem fixed.
   We apologize for the inconvenience 1.</p>';
// Send the order information to the administrator.

}

} 

else { // Rollback and report the problem.

@mysqli_rollback($dbc);
@mysql_close($dbc);

echo '<p>Your order could not be processed due to a system error.
   You will be contacted in order to have the problem fixed.
   We apologize for the inconvenience 2.</p>';
// Send the order information to the administrator.
}

?>
</div></div>

<?php  
include ('./includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a really simple example that uses stored procedures which you might find useful.

Full script here : http://pastie.org/1268992

Hope it helps :)

**Example stored procedure calls**

```
start transaction;

call insert_order(1);

call insert_order_item(1,1,2);
call insert_order_item(1,2,4);
call insert_order_item(1,3,6);

commit;
```

**Example PHP script**

```
<?php

// dummy session data

$userID = 1; 

$cart = array(
    array("product_id" => 1, "qty" => 2, "item_id" => 0, "price" => 0, "subtotal" => 0), 
    array("product_id" => 2, "qty" => 4, "item_id" => 0, "price" => 0, "subtotal" => 0),    
    array("product_id" => 3, "qty" => 6, "item_id" => 0, "price" => 0, "subtotal" => 0));

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "foo_dbo", "pass", "foo_db", 3306);

try{
    $conn->autocommit(FALSE); // start transaction

    // create the order 

    $sql = sprintf("call insert_order(%d)", $userID);

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    $result->close();

    $orderID = $row["order_id"]; //  new order_id returned by sproc
    $conn->next_result();   

    // loop your cart and insert order items

    foreach($cart as $k => $v){

        $sql = sprintf("call insert_order_item(%d,%d,%d)", $orderID, $v["product_id"],$v["qty"]);

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        $result->close();

        $cart[$k]["item_id"] = $row["item_id"]; // save data returned by sproc incase you need it ??
        $cart[$k]["price"] = $row["price"];
        $cart[$k]["subtotal"] = $row["subtotal"];

        $conn->next_result();   
    }
    $conn->commit(); //all OK so commit order/order items...

    echo sprintf("your order no. is %s<br/>", $orderID);

    $total = 0;
    foreach($cart as $k => $v){
        $total += $v["subtotal"];
        echo sprintf("item_id=%s, product_id=%s, price=%s, qty=%s, subtotal=%s<br/>", 
            $v["item_id"],$v["product_id"],$v["price"],$v["qty"],$v["subtotal"]);
    }
    echo sprintf("order total = %s<br/>", $total);

}
catch(exception $ex){
    //handle errros and rollback
    $conn->rollback();
    echo sprintf("order error - %s<br/>", $ex->getMessage()); 
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

**Example MySQL script**

```
-- TABLES

drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varbinary(32) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists products;
create table products
(
product_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(255) unique not null,
price decimal(10,2) not null default 0
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists orders;
create table orders
(
order_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
user_id int unsigned not null,
order_date datetime not null,
total decimal(10,2) not null default 0,
key (user_id)
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists order_items;
create table order_items
(
item_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
order_id int unsigned not null,
product_id smallint unsigned not null,
qty smallint unsigned not null default 0,
price decimal(10,2) not null default 0,
subtotal decimal(10,2) not null default 0,
key (order_id),
key (product_id)
)
engine=innodb;

-- STORED PROCEDURES

drop procedure if exists insert_order;

delimiter #

create procedure insert_order
(
in p_user_id int unsigned
)
proc_main:begin

declare v_order_id int unsigned default 0;

    insert into orders (user_id, order_date, total) values (p_user_id, now(), 0);

    set v_order_id = last_insert_id();

    -- do more things with v_order_id ??

    select v_order_id as order_id;

end proc_main #

delimiter ;

drop procedure if exists insert_order_item;

delimiter #

create procedure insert_order_item
(
in p_order_id int unsigned,
in p_product_id smallint unsigned,
in p_qty smallint unsigned
)
proc_main:begin

declare v_item_id int unsigned default 0;
declare v_price decimal(10,2) default 0;
declare v_subtotal decimal(10,2) default 0;

    select price into v_price from products where product_id = p_product_id;

    set v_subtotal =  v_price * p_qty;

    insert into order_items (order_id, product_id, qty, price, subtotal) values 
        (p_order_id, p_product_id, p_qty, v_price, v_subtotal);

    set v_item_id = last_insert_id();

    -- do more things with v_item_id ??

    update orders set total = total + v_subtotal where order_id = p_order_id;

    select p_order_id as order_id, v_item_id as item_id, 
        v_price as price, v_subtotal as subtotal;

end proc_main #

delimiter ;

-- TEST DATA

insert into users (username) values ('f00'),('bar'),('alpha'),('beta'),('gamma');
insert into products (name, price) values ('product 1', 9.99),('product 2',12.34),('product 3',32.50),('product 4',1.99);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will give these a try and write back soon(ish ;P)

Comment: I didn't have any luck with the above code.


This script is on my 'view cart' option and Im just trying to get the total variable to come across to the submit_cart.php script.



$total = 0; // Total cost of the order.

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

// Calculate the total and subtotals.
$subtotal = $_SESSION['cart'][$row
   ['products_id']]['quantity'] *
   $_SESSION['cart'][$row ['products_id']]['price'];
$total += $subtotal;

echo "Print variables here";
} // End of the WHILE loop.

mysql_close($dbc);

Comment: it's a very simple process so i'm wondering what you didnt have luck with ?

Comment: My php experience is relatively minimal so for me it is pretty difficult to get to work. I can kind of see what your code is doing but trying to implement it with the code I have shown above is beyond my knowledge of php so far. I can tell from your code that the MySQL section inserts the tables to the database and that the second file is the php script. Where do the stored procedure files sit in relation to these files?

Comment: Stored procedures are created in your database along with your tables and views and any other db objects (they are just user defined functions that operate on your tables) If you look at the fullscript i sent you http://pastie.org/1268992 there are 2 parts PHP and SQL. Save the PHP part in a separate file cart.php and save the SQL part in a separate file called cart.sql. Now all you need to do is put the cart.php in your web root and run the cart.sql against an existing or new db. Finally, amend cart.php and change the db connection string - good luck

Comment: Ok, Will try this but in regards to the part of the php code which has the database connection string ie '$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "foo_dbo", "pass", "foo_db", 3306);'
What is the 3306 for? Also is foo_dbo for the username and foo_db for the database name? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you have set the total variable to 0 thats why the total cost on the order table shows zero.

```
$total = 0; // Total cost of the order.
```

Comment: I was wondering how I get the total variable from my "view_cart" script (link for this is at the top of the page under 'this page') into this script and into the database?